# Additional RESTful methods and actions DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have a model that has several columns I want to present to the interface to update as different pages.  My question deals with what is the best rails-y way to organize your routes and controller actions.

For example, a User has a "Profile" and a "Billing Address".  Both pages contain columns only from the User model, they are required and one-to-one, and small, so an additional model seems like unnecessary overhead.

It seems like I have to add a GET and a PUT for each different view I want to present, is that right?  So instead of just edit/update, I'd need edit_profile/update_profile and edit_billing/update_billing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without a Profile model, I think you still can use ProfileController and views for profile like 'views/update.html.erb', and make it route as '/users/123/profile/'.

In my opinion, we don't need to mapping every view or controller to one model strictly. Rails is based on ROA, but here the "resource" can be more abstract.